# Integral depending on $n$ variables through a norm

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $\lVert .\rVert_2:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be the Euclidean norm. I wish to show that
$$
I=\int_{s\in \mathbb{R}^n}\exp\{-\alpha\lVert s\rVert_2\}ds
$$
is finite. This looks simple enough because the norm maps the vectors in the real line, therefore it should collapse to the integral of the exponential function with a negative coefficient that it's simple enough. However, how should I justify the change of variables? I know I can use the Jacobian when we have an injective differentiable application, but i can't apply it here, right? It's differentiable, but not injective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\|s\|_2$ is the distance $r$ of a point $s$ from the origin. So if you write the integral in *spherical coordinates*, the integrand becomes $e^{-\alpha r}$, which you know how to integrate over $r$ from zero to infinity. You then just need to take care of the integrals over all of the angles in spherical coordinates -- giving you the area of the surface of the unit sphere in ${\mathbb R}^n$ because the integrand does not depend on these angles.

Comment: Well, that's a really well-laid hint. Thanks! I think I can do it now.